# Customize form in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am making an form of 5 inputs but I am not able to do styling on it as I am not that much pro in CSS . I want to customize the form in a box of width 650px and height : 500px .

Here is my html code:

```
            <div className= {styles.form}>
            <form>
              <div className='input-container1 ic1'>
            <div class="row mb-3 ">
              
          <label for="query"  className='col-sm-2 col-form- 
          label'>Query(q1)</label>
          <div className="col-sm-10">
            <input type="search" className="form-control i1" id="inputSearch3" placeholder='q1'/>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div className="row mb-3 input-container ic2">
        <label for="query2"  className='col-sm-2 col-form-label'>Query(q2)</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="search" className="form-control" id="inputLocation3" placeholder='q2'/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="row mb-3 input-container ic3">
        <label for="query"  className='col-sm-2 col-form-label'>Query(q3)</label>
          <div className="col-sm-10">

            <input type="search" className="form-control" id="inputDuration3" placeholder='q3'/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="row mb-3 input-container ic4">
        <label for="query"  className='col-sm-2 col-form-label'>Query(q4)</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="search" className="form-control" id="inputPages3" placeholder='q4'/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="row mb-3 input-container ic5">
        <label for="query"  className='col-sm-2 col-form-label'>Query(q5)</label>
          <div className="col-sm-10">
            <input type="search" className="form-control" id="inputResults3" placeholder='q5'/>
          </div>
        </div>
        </form>
                  
        </div>
```

Here is my css:

```
    .form{
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 60px;
    padding: 60px;
}
label, input {
    display: block;
    padding: 6px;
}

input{
    border-radius: 4px;
}

label {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.i1{
    width: 70px;
}
```

Although I have added width to my input field , but it is not working .

[image: Here is my image]

Comment: U need to add your HTML and the CSS you tried

Comment: You are not likely to get a good response with this question. Create the simplest, shortest code example that reproduces the problem. Take a look at [How to write effective questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex).

Comment: @ArchitGargi how can you customize this bro ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your code:

1. You haven't given your `form` element a class but you're using `.form` class selector in your CSS. That's why it's not applying styles.
2. You haven't applied a `width` property to your form. By the way, it's better to apply `max-width` property so it stays responsive.
3. In order to apply widths to input fields, it's better to use 100% instead of pixels, i.e. `width: 100%;` so the fields use the parent element's width. In this case, having `max-width: 650px;` on your `.form` makes all input fields automatically size to adjust this.
4. Applying height to `form` element isn't recommended as it will add a scrollbar for overflow. But I have added this in the code below in case you want to keep it.

Here is the revised code:

```css
.form {
  max-width: 650px; /* Use max-width not width so it remains responsive */
  height: 500px; /* Not recommended */
  padding: 60px;
  margin: 10px auto 60px; /* To make centered */
}

label,
input {
  display: block;
  padding: 6px;
  width: 100%;
}


input {
  border-radius: 4px;
}


label {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.form-row {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 -15px;
}

.form-row > div {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<form class="form">
  <div className='input-container1 ic1'>
    <div class="row mb-3 ">
      <label for="query" className='col-sm-2 col-form-label'>Query(q1)</label>
      <div className="col-sm-10">
        <input type="search" className="form-control i1" id="inputSearch3" placeholder='q1' />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div className="row mb-3 input-container ic2">
      <label for="query2" className='col-sm-2 col-form-label'>Query(q2)</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="search" className="form-control" id="inputLocation3" placeholder='q2' />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className="row mb-3 input-container ic3">
      <label for="query" className='col-sm-2 col-form-label'>Query(q3)</label>
      <div className="col-sm-10">
        <input type="search" className="form-control" id="inputDuration3" placeholder='q3' />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
    <div className="row mb-3 input-container ic4">
      <label for="query" className='col-sm-2 col-form-label'>Query(q4)</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="search" className="form-control" id="inputPages3" placeholder='q4' />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className="row mb-3 input-container ic5">
      <label for="query" className='col-sm-2 col-form-label'>Query(q5)</label>
      <div className="col-sm-10">
        <input type="search" className="form-control" id="inputResults3" placeholder='q5' />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I want that form on left side of screen in an invisible box of width 650px as I have something at right side also . And also can you make the length for query1 larger , query2 and query 3 in same line , query4 and query5 in same line ??

Comment: Not sure what you mean by an invisible box. For showing multiple fields in one line, you need to wrap them in a div and apply `display: flex; margin: 0 -15px;`, then apply `width: 100%; padding: 0 15px;` to the inner div. I've updated my answer above to reflect this.